# Can we use reactJS with amCharts

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

Was wondering if it is technically possible to use reactJS with amCharts charting library.  If yes, has anyone tried or has a demo that I could reference.  Also, is the rendering of amCharts experience expected to improve as a result of using reactJS?

Comment: Check this out. This is the official amchart react component. https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-react/ It's quite new though.

Comment: It solves many problems. You don't have to give an id nor do you have to call validateData() if your data changes. Keep a track on the concerned Github repo. amcharts is quite popular and they are sure to update it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amchart using ReactJs Demo(Pie Graph)

```
import React from "react";
import AmCharts from "@amcharts/amcharts3-react";
import { graphType } from "../Graph/GraphType";
import { toolTipType } from "../Graph/ToolTipType";

class PieGraph extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  dataProvider: JSON.parse(props.dataSet.Data)
};
}
render() {
    // Render the chart
    var graphProperty = this.props.dataSet;
    var controlId=this.props.controlKey;
     var legendId="legendDiv_"+controlId;

    var chartType = graphProperty.GraphType;
    var is3DChart = graphProperty.Is3DChart;
    var toolTipFormat = graphProperty.ToolTipFormat;
    var isLegendRequired = graphProperty.IsLegendRequired;
    var subTitle = graphProperty.SubTitle;


    var radious="";
    var innerRadius="";
    if (chartType == graphType.Doughnut) {
        radious = "30%";
        innerRadius = "35%";
    }

     var title=[{
        text : subTitle,
         id: "Title-1"
        //size: 15
    }];

    var depth3D="";
    var angle="";
    if (is3DChart)
    {
        depth3D = 8;
        angle = 20;
    }

    var labelText= "[[percents]]%([[value]])";
    var balloonText= "[[sliceText]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>";

    if (toolTipFormat == "None" || toolTipFormat == toolTipType.None) {
        labelText = "[[value]]";
        balloonText = "";
    }
    else if (toolTipFormat == "ShowValue" || toolTipFormat == toolTipType.ShowValue) {
        labelText = "[[value]]";
        balloonText = "[[sliceText]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b></span>";
    }
    else if (toolTipFormat == "ShowPercentage" || toolTipFormat == toolTipType.ShowPercentage) {
        labelText = "[[percents]]%";
        balloonText = "[[sliceText]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'>([[percents]]%)</b></span>";
    }

    var marginTop=10;
    if(subTitle== "")
    marginTop = -50;


    var legend="";
    var isfromRportDetail=1;//Temporary assume true....
    if(isLegendRequired)
    {

            var legendEqualWidths=false;
            var lagendPosition="";
            var labelWidth="";
            var legendMarginLeft="";
            var legendalign="";
            if (isfromRportDetail) {  //added this condition for reportdetail charts for else in running other report chart
                lagendPosition = "right";
                legendMarginLeft = 0;
                legendEqualWidths = true;
                legendalign="right";
            }
            else {
                legendalign = "center";
                legendEqualWidths = false;
                labelWidth = 1;
            }

            legend=[{
                   divId:legendId,
                    color : "#999999",
                    markerSize : 3,
                    markerBorderThickness : 4,
                    valueText : "",
                    truncateLabels : 15,
                    position :lagendPosition,
                    marginLeft : legendMarginLeft,
                    equalWidths :labelWidth,
                    align : legendalign,
                    labelWidth : legendEqualWidths,
                    markerType: "circle",
                    listeners: [{
                                event: "clickSlice",
                                method: function (event) {
                                    if (event.dataItem.dataContext.url != undefined) {
                                            if (event.dataItem.dataContext.url != "")
                                            popdlgrs(event.dataItem.dataContext.url, "_blank", 800, 650);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            return "";
                                    }
                                }
                    }]

            }];

    }


        return (
            <AmCharts.React
                type="pie"
                theme="light"
                startAngle="355"
                color="#999999"
                labelRadius="20"
                titles={title} 
                pullOutRadius="12%"
                precision="2"
                percentPrecision="2"
                thousandsSeparator=","
                decimalSeparator="."
                marginBottom="10"
                marginTop={marginTop}
                radius={radious}
                depth3D = {depth3D}
                angle = {angle}
                innerRadius={innerRadius}
                dataProvider={this.state.dataProvider}
                valueField={graphProperty.ChartDataFields}
                titleField={graphProperty.ChartCetegoryFields}
                labelText = {labelText}
                balloonText = {balloonText}
                colors = {["#ED807D", "#F0BF73", "#B5D766", "#9BDDDB", "#8EC5E4", "#D094DC", "#CDDC39", "#3396da", "#b85acc", "#60b2ae", "#85ae21", "#eda22d", "#e54c4f", "#D66C6E", "#8BC24A", "#70D5C7", "#ED807D", "#F0BF73", "#B5D766", "#9BDDDB", "#8EC5E4", "#D094DC", "#CDDC39", "#3396da", "#b85acc", "#60b2ae", "#85ae21", "#eda22d", "#e54c4f", "#D66C6E", "#8BC24A", "#70D5C7"]}
                legend={legend}
                balloon={[{
                    fixedPosition: "true",
                    drop: "true"
                }]}

                listeners={ 
                    [{
                                event: "clickSlice",
                                method: function (event) 
                                       {

                                                    if (event.dataItem.dataContext.url != undefined) {
                                                                if (event.dataItem.dataContext.url != "")
                                                                        popdlgrs(event.dataItem.dataContext.url, "_blank", 800, 650);
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        return "";
                                                    }

                                      }
                   }]
                }



            />);
}

 }
 export default PieGraph;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you basically need to make a wrapper component and hook up the initialisation of the library. The config is usually best passed to the component as props.

React is good at rendering React components. Anything rendered by non-react libraries will be like a black box to React and you will see no benefit. In fact, you may end up with a big overhead if you don't code your wrapper component well and keep reinitialising or updating the library even though config hasn't changed.

We use highcharts for column charts in the project I'm working on. The code is not open source and also far too large and complex to be of use as a simple example, but here's the bare bones of what it looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

export default React.createClass({
    displayName: 'BarChart',

    componentDidMount: function () {
        this._initChart();
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps) {
        return nextProps.chartData != this.props.chartData || nextProps.emptyMessage != this.props.emptyMessage;
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        this._initChart();
    },

    _initChart: function () {
        //do not attempt to render if there's no data, insert placeholder instead
        //since it's a jquery plugin we also render the placeholder with jquery to keep React out of it
        if (!this.props.chartData || this.props.chartData.length == 0) {
            var jqContainer = $(this.refs.container);
            var height = jqContainer.height() + 'px';
            jqContainer.html($('<span class="bar-chart-empty-placeholder"><i class="' +
                ((this.props.emptyMessage.indexOf('Loading') > -1) ? 'fa fa-spinner fa-pulse' : '') + '"></i> ' +
                this.props.emptyMessage + '</span>').css({'height': height, 'line-height': height}));
            return;
        }

        //data transformation
        //some logic here, transforming data from API to format expected by highcharts

        $(this.refs.container).highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                tickWidth: 0,
                tickPixelInterval: 130,
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return dateFormatter(this.value, dateGrain);
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: '0',
                labels: {
                    format: '{value} %'
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'percent',
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: seriesArray
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        //output the title and the container div, contents will be rendered by highcharts
        return (
            <div className="chart-legend clearfix">
                <h4 className="pull-left">{this.props.title}</h4>

                <div ref="container"
                     style={{height: '300px', paddingLeft: 0, marginTop: '50px', marginBottom: '30px'}}
                ></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

For additional optimization, if title never changes, we could call _initChart in shouldComponentUpdate when props have changed and have it always return true so that the container html never gets rerendered by React.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a good start.  Quick question (may sound naive) - if the chart properties are changed or new series added by a user interactively, will it be react or highcharts doing the heavy lifting of updating the DOM and rendering the revised chart.  Will the concept of virtualDOM help in this case.

Comment: Nope, no effect from React, the chart library will have to do all the heavy lifting, but those libraries have mostly been around longer than React so I'd have some faith. If you really want React all the way you could look for a suitable React-only chart components like http://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-chart or make your own components that render svg instead of the usual html.

Comment: Thank you - that helps.  Just one small point - Highcharts render html (canvas) but amCharts is all svg

Comment: I'm pretty sure highcharts is rendering SVG (source: using it and inspecting the DOM right now). If you want canvas try Flot. Also note that SVG is plain DOM so React can render it with DOM renderer, but you'd need a custom one to render to canvas with a React component.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks